# Probability of exactly one defective unit

Tags: probability

Assume 5 out of 100 units are defective. We pick 3 out of the 100 units at random.

What is the probability that exactly one unit is defective?

---

My answer would be

$P(\text{Defect}=1) = P(\text{Defect})\times P(\text{Not defect})\times P(\text{Not defect}) = 5/100 \times 95/99 \times 94/98$

However, I am not sure whether or not this is correct or not. Can someone verify?

Comment: You can choose the defective in three different ways. Also the number of non-defective units is  $95$ not  $94$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I meant 95/99 and 94/98. But then are you saying that I have to calculate like this: P(D=1) = {DDN}U{DND}U{NDD}, where D is af defective unit and N is a non-defective unit?

Comment: Yes. You will get the same answer mentioned below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer should be $$\frac{\binom{5}{1}\binom{95}{2}}{\binom{100}{3}}$$ Since we want the total number of ways to choose 3 meeting the criteria over the total number of ways to choose 3 out of the 100.

Comment: I don't understand why it's 500 instead of 100? But I didn't think of the binomial distribution, thank you!

Comment: sorry, the 500 was a typo...

Comment: @CruZ This isn't the binomial distribution, it's actually called the *hypergeometric* distribution.

Comment: Ah thank you for clearing that up, my mistake! Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a suggestion how to proceed as ordering does not play a role

- Choose one defective item: $\binom{5}{1}$
- Choose two non-defective ones: $\binom{95}{2}$
- Chose any three: $\binom{100}{3}$
  $$P(\mbox{"exactly 1 defective"}) = \frac{\binom{5}{1}\cdot \binom{95}{2}}{\binom{100}{3}}$$